# How to unminimize a min.css file?

Tags: html, css, minimize, unminify

I tried to use an online unminifier (http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/). I replaced the minimized with the unminized text. Afterwards I called the URL, the whole website was not layouted.

But I really need to configure some css-classes, just integrating a new css-lib would not help.

What did I wrong? Maybe the unminifier does not work and you can recommend me a better one?

Comment: This is how I do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173905/chrome-developer-tools-inspect-prettified-css If the formatter is screwing up the CSS, there may be an error in your CSS.

Comment: You can try http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used [this one](http://unminify.com/) and it's always worked for me :)

Comment: Nice, this tool worked for me! Thank you for response !

Answer (score 0):

The website updated 6 years ago (also [github page](https://github.com/mrcoles/cssunminifier)). So maybe there is problem about it.

I recommend you to use Atom editor. Use [this package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) with Atom. It always works for me.